# Design Question - is it possible to design a XML generic enough to process list of objects

Tags: xml, generics

I want to know if an XML can store Object of Different types.
Something like

```
              <XML> 
              <Object1> 
                <Attributes of Object1> 
              </Object1> 
             <Object2>
              <Attributes of Object 2> 
             </Object2> 
            </XML>
```

So to give a background what we are trying to do is currently we have only 2 objects which we want to pass as an XML to a ESB, but eventually we will want to add different objects the list.So want to make the XML very generic so that when we add more objects then minimal changes are needed. Any ideas will be appreciated.

This is more of a design question

It is design questions

Comment: XML has no schema, you can put whatever you want into it. Did you try?

Comment: Sure. And I would recommend based on your question using something like object type= and not object1, object2

Answer (score 0):

Many people use "generic" formats like

```
<Object type="Person">
  <Attribute name="age" value="24"/>
  <Attribute name="hair-color" value="blue"/>
</Object>
```

and in my view it's a terrible mistake. They forget that XML is already extensible, and you get just as much flexibility by writing

```
<Person age="24" hair-color="blue"/>
```

The latter form is easier to generate, easier to process, easier to validate, and is just as easy to extend.